# androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton throwing android.view.InflateException because of translucent background

Tags: java, android, flutter, flutter-plugin

I have been working on a flutter plugin for the last few days. I am trying to implement and existing media player into a flutter widget. However since the media player's SDK uses MediaRouteButtons in the player view I have been getting an `android.view.InflateException` when trying to inflate it.

The core reason is because the background cannot be translucent. I have tried to set the main activity's `colorPrimary` through custom themes or using built in themes with opaque backgrounds. This has no effect and the error is persistant.

I suspect that flutter is adding its own theme somewhere in the mix and this is causing the issue, but I couldn't find any helpful information on that.

The SDK itself is not the problem since I am testing the same functionality with an empty view with only a `MediaRouteButton`.
Here is my layout:

```
<androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton
        android:id="@+id/media_route_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I am creating a `PlatformView` and in the constructor I am trying to inflate the view. This is the constructor and the `LayoutInflater` is the one throwing the exception.

```
FlutterPlayerView(Context context, BinaryMessenger messenger, int id) {
        this.channel = new MethodChannel(messenger, CHANNEL + id);
        this.channel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.button_view, null);
        this.buttonView = view.findViewById(R.id.media_route_button);
    }
```

This is a custom theme I have tried using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#FFFFFFFF</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I set it in the plugin manifest and also in the app manifest, and even in the generated `MainActivity.java` activity by using `setTheme()`.

Nothing seems to help, so any leads would be great. If someone understands how flutter sets the themes for the plugin `Activity` an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by setting the theme of the activity from the `context` passed into my `PlatforView` constructor

Before

```
FlutterPlayerView(Context context, BinaryMessenger messenger, int id) {
    this.channel = new MethodChannel(messenger, CHANNEL + id);
    this.channel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.button_view, null);
    this.buttonView = view.findViewById(R.id.media_route_button);
}
```

After

```
FlutterPlayerView(Context context, BinaryMessenger messenger, int id) {
    this.channel = new MethodChannel(messenger, CHANNEL + id);
    this.channel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
        
    // android:colorPrimary is opaque in AppTheme
    context.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme); 
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.button_view, null);
    this.buttonView = view.findViewById(R.id.media_route_button);
}
```

Also there is a way to do it by implementing the `ActivityAware` interface in your Flutter plugin and overriding the `onAttachedToActivity` and `onRettachedToActivity` methods.

For example:

```
public class YourFlutterPlugin implements FlutterPlugin, ActivityAware{
    //...

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToActivity(@NonNull ActivityPluginBinding binding) {
        Context context = binding.getActivity();
        // Your code for sending the context to the view
        // Example:  platformView.setContext(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReattachedToActivity(@NonNull ActivityPluginBinding binding) {
        Context context = binding.getActivity();
        // Your code for sending the context to the view
        // Example:  platformView.setContext(context);
    }

  // ...
}
```